# Iterative Addition of Variables to Model Based on P Value

Tags: regression, correlation, model-selection, p-value

Suppose I have 64 columns that I have chosen out of 500+ columns based on the fact that they have the highest pairwise correlation (is this a good way?).  I take 16 of these columns and run a simple multi-variate regression.  I find that 4 of these columns have P values less than .05.  Can I go back, do this for the next set of 16 (mutually exclusive from the first set), check the P values, and add the successful columns to the model without issue?  Moreover, is it okay to only pick the four mutually exclusive sets of 16 columns, or would I have to actually pick 64 choose 16 times and find commonalities between each set?

I have a feeling there is something wrong with the way I am doing the above, so I hope someone can shed some light on the proper way to go about this.  As well, please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve this question.

Comment: Most such *ad hoc* statistical procedures perform poorly compared to extant, well-known ones.  What have you done to verify that this procedure has any useful properties?

Comment: @whuber I suppose I am looking at this in the opposite direction.  I believe this procedure is incorrect because from what I understand the p-values of the final model will change dramatically because the correlation between those variables has not been checked (as the sets of 16 are mutually exclusive).  I guess I am in part interested in why this is incorrect.  This made me wonder, though, what would happen if all columns were correlated with each other exhaustively.  It appears to me this resolves the issue (inefficiently) because all correlations have been assessed in advance.